Confused about the sort() function in C++
I've just done a problem on Leetcode. But I was confused about the sort() function of C++.
This is more detail about it:

Given an array of integers nums, sort the array in increasing order based on the frequency of the values. If multiple values have the same frequency, sort them in decreasing order.
-Input: An array
-Output: Sorted array following the problem's rule

Here is my code.
First code snippet:
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
        std::map<int, int> hm;
        for (int numb : nums)
            hm[numb] ++ ;
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [&](int a,int b){
            if(hm[a] == hm[b])
                return a > b;
            return hm[a] <  hm[b];
        });
    }
}

The second code snippet:
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
        std::map<int, int> hm;
        for (int numb : nums)
            hm[numb] ++ ;

        vector<int> arr;
        for(auto &[numb,freq] :  hm){
            while(freq > 0){
                arr.push_back(numb);
                freq--;
            }
        }
        std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [&](int a, int b){
            if( hm[a] == hm[b])
                return a > b;
            else
                return hm[a] <  hm[b];
        });
        return arr;
    }
};

Here's an example
-Input: [1,1,2,2,2,3]
-Output for first code snippet: [3,1,1,2,2,2]
-Output for second code snippet: [3,2,2,2,1,1]
The thing that I don't understand is why the second one's sort() function seems to not be working? Can anybody help me to make it clear, please?
I tried two code snippets with the same function but it seems to return two different results.

Why there is code after return nums; in second snippet?

Have you debugged your code? And did you get to all the expected lines of code? Or did you seen anything unexpected when stepping line by line through your code? The thing with Leetcode is that you should still develop your code locally and debug it if something doesn't work

" but it seems return back the two differnt results...." Start using a debugger. See what is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems.

Second snippet is unnessary creating a new arr when its already sorted and nums is created

The first function doesn't return anything, it can't work. The first function should work as the first one intended (ignoring compiler warnings).

To mirror the first comment (by @kiner_shah), why isn't there a return nums; in the first code snippet?

Sorry everyone I've edited my code, there's no return nums in second code snippet and thanks a lot.

Thank everyone, I realized my problem and solved it.

@DavidAdonis then you should either post an answer explaining the problem and solution, or else delete the question.

Both functions are wrong.
The 1st function does not return anything, which is undefined behavior.
The 2nd function return's prematurely, skipping half of its code.
The compiler should have warned you about both mistakes. If it didn't, turn up the warning level.

Many thanks to you.

I don't know why but the compiler of leetcode can run both of code snippets, as I metioned in my post, two code snippets return two different results. It was my fault when writing my second snippet in my post but I've edited. I want to try to debug but when I tried it on devC, there're some errors I couldn't fix (I'm too amateur to fix it, my bad),and  leetcode's debug is only for premium so  I'm still stuck, can you help me please!!!

@DavidAdonis even with your edit, the 1st code snippet still has UB, so trying to compare the results of the 2 snippets is useless.

thank you, I've seen clearly my problem. I think I was a little silly when did not observe the code in more detail and did not debug it
