External Data Structure Used in Custom Comparison Function in C++
I have array of numbers and I have to sort them based on there frequency in ascending order
and if both numbers are same then sort them in decreasing order
what I did was I create unordered_map and store number's frequency  in map
and Inside custom sort function I used it to sort the numbers
Implemention look's like this
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<int,int>map;

    bool operator ()(const int &a,const int &b){
        if(map[a]==map[b])
            return a>b;

        return map[a]<map[b];
    }

    vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<int>answer;

        for(auto num:nums)
            map[num]++;

        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),Solution());

        return nums;
    }
};

but when I use this custom function I gives me wrong answe like
for input nums = [1,1,2,2,2,3]

output is [3,2,2,2,1,1]

which is not expected !! but functions implementation looks good
so what expexted is
Expected [3,1,1,2,2,2]
to achive this I see solution and they used lamda function for custom sorting
Implementation of lamda function is like
sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),[&](int a, int b) {
            if (map[a] == map[b]) {
                return a > b;
            }
            return map[a] < map[b];
        });

body part of my function and lamda function is similiar
but why I am getting wrong answer ?
Thank you

You create and pass to std::sort a temporary Solution() object whose map is empty.

I'm sorry, but this shows all too well why so-called competition sites should not be used to learn the basics of programming or programming languages. A good book or two, good online resources or actual classes should teach you all the basics and much more.

@Quimby but if I cout map values in the function then it give me some ouput,

Yea of course, but that is not the map you are passing to std::sort, each instance of Solution has its own independent map object and you passed to std::sort a new Solution object. Heed the advice of @Someprogrammerdude and grab a book to learn language concepts, these sites will not teach you.

Use a lambda man. That's so convenient. And your comparator function needs improvement. You are accessing map so many times, it should be only twice (one for a, one for b).

You seemed to create a second account after this question had been closed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78781522/confused-about-the-sort-function-in-c

I tried this, seeing some weird behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/v98c9c5T4

I tried 3 solutions: https://godbolt.org/z/rWKzbjKdT, lambda one looks better. Others were showing some weird output (too many destructor calls).

@3CxEZiVlQ no way I here for learning ! not for getting upvotes
thank u

@Quimby sure thank you

As Quimby has already mentioned in the comments, you are passing a temporary instance of Solution as the Compare parameter of std::sort but this temporary is a new instance of Solution and all it’s member variables and member functions are in the default state. In this default state, Solution::map is a default constructed std::unordered_map and not the std::unordered_map currently in the original instance of Solution so it has no knowledge of the frequencies currently stored in the original. To use the original as the comparator function for std::sort, pass the original to std::sort.

std::sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(), *this);

I see some weird behavior, too many destructor calls, why is that: https://godbolt.org/z/v98c9c5T4

This answer should help you.

std::ref(*this) - this avoids all those copies. Thanks for the link.
